# MongoDb Schema for Account creation with subscription plan

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have to create an Account creation schema which is basically a three-step process.

In step 1, we have Email-id with a password and confirm the password.

step 2: User can select the subscription plan which is basic, standard and premium .then after

step3: Payment module where we ask for card details and payment for the selected plan.

after the successful subscription user redirected into the dashboard. I have to design the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - there is no reason to keep confirmation password. this should be checked in client side only.
So we need only the email and password (hashed: password + salt[email/userid])
Make sure when user register you check the email

Step 2 - should be index let's say 0-not subscribed, 1-basic, 2-standard, 3-premium

Step 3 - This better for you not to keep. just use the API of online clearing to get the payment and confirmation of the payment.

I would have added the fields of subscribe date. and the date the subscription will expired.
good luck.

**EDITED**

```
let schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, validate: validateEmail }, //The validate Email should be a function that get as value the email and return true or false if it is valid! (email format/not duplicated)
    subscription: { type: Number },// 0-non. 1-basic, 2-standard, 3-premium (this will be set by the payment)
    subscriptionDate: { type: Date },
    subscriptionExpr: { type: Date }//This also will be set by the payment, and will be checked before any service giving. making sure the subscription is still valid.
});
```

This is the most basic form of scheme you need. you could make it more complex by making the last three fields in array for tracking past subscription plans the user had or so.

Comment: can you please design a schema for the above scenario. I am using mongoose/MongoDB